# How to search on a many-to-many field

Tags: go, struct, go-gorm

Let's assume I have the below structs

```golang
type Job struct {
    ID          string               `sql:"type:uuid;primary_key;"`
    Title       string               `json:"title,omitempty"`
    Skills      []*skill.Skill       `json:"skills,omitempty"gorm:"many2many:job_skill;"`
}

type Skill struct {
    Name string `json:"name" gorm:"primary_key"`
}
```

To query all the jobs I do:

```golang
jobs := &[]Job{}
gorm.DB.Preload("Skills").Find(&jobs)
```

How do I search for a `Job` that contains a certain skill? I have tried the below but it says the column does not exist.

```golang
s := "golang"
jobs := &[]Job{}

gorm.DB.Preload("Skills").Where("skill = ?", s).Find(&jobs)
```

I can see my issues, `=` doesn't seem to be the correct operator as it needs to search in a list. And it also isn't loading the join table as I assumed it would

Debug output

```sql
pq: column "skill" does not exist
SELECT * FROM "jobs" WHERE skill = 'golang'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Preload` method and the `Associations` feature help you load your fields by constructing basic SQL queries based on the relationships you have created. Queries like loading all skills for a specific job (or jobs). But it doesn't go any more complex than that.

Rather, think of `go-gorm` as a way to construct your SQL queries and load the data into your models.

Having that in mind, one solution would be to use `Joins` to include the `skill` table.

```
gorm.DB.Preload("Skills")
   .Joins("INNER JOIN job_skill js ON js.job_id = jobs.id").
   .Joins("INNER JOIN skill s ON s.id = js.skill_id").
   .Where("s.name = ?", s).Find(&jobs)
```

Comment: Nice, works! New to SQL so have been avoiding it hence using Gorm, but looks like I'll need to dive into it a bit more.